# What is 'oip' in the zimbra mail server logs?

Tags: email, email-client, zimbra

This is the first time I am trying to understand Zimbra logs. I noticed that every action (like deletion of a mail, addition of an incoming mail etc.) is logged in the mailServer.log file. Since emails can also be deleted (from java code remotely), I wanted to know which IP the command came from. For example, for the below log line (taken from https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Log_Files), what exactly is 'oip' (originating IP).

Is it the IP address of the server from where the command originated ? If yes, then we can find who remotely sent the command (delete/add/expunge etc.). Is that correct ?

```
2013-08-30 11:19:41,043 INFO  [qtp2050551931-94:http://127.0.0.1:8080/service/soap/AuthRequest] [name=user1@example.com;oip=5.6.7.8;ua=zclient/8.0.4_GA_5737;] mbxmgr - Mailbox 3 account abcdef8f-1234-5678-9012-8abcdefe2658 LOADED
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, it's the address of the client or, if you have one, the proxy that originated the request

You can log public IP following the steps in this wiki

https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Log_Files#Logging_the_Originating_IP